# Swift - Proper Way to Implement Expandable Cell List

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have an XCode/Swift usecase for which I am unclear on the correct way to implement.

[image]

I want to do as is done above, but I want 1) Each cell to be **static** 2) I want to click on a cell and have it expand to include another view. Eg, if I click on the date I want it to expand to show a calendar, and shift the cells below it down. I want to also be able to close tge cell.

I have considered and tried using the UITableView and implementing my own expand/collapse there, however I am confused as to how I would imbed another view in that, and more specifically, how that would work with static cells that I coded on Storyboard, since I would have to implement cellForRowAt with a static cell. I could also do this without using a TableViewController, but I am not sure how I would approach that.

Any thoughts on how to approach this problem would be great.

Comment: I recommend you to read following article it might be helpful for you. https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Comment: This article assumes my tableview is dynamic.